# Store Kit transaction failing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store, transactions, storekit

I'm attempting to test a Store Kit transaction with the iPhone 3.0 SDK. I am basing my code off the sample code in the Store Kit Programming Guide, but I keep getting failed transactions (status: SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed). However, the transaction's error property is nil, so that doesn't shed any light on the situation.

When I attempt to purchase the product, I am able to log-in with a test account and accept the purchase, but then I get a dialog box that says:

"You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded. Tap OK to download it now."

When I tap "OK" nothing happens. My transactionObserver doesn't get any more messages sent to it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue with consumable items.  It turns out the above answer was correct.  My teammate accidentally deleted my test account.  Everything works fine after I created a new one.

Comment: I had similar issue and creating a new test account fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my test account had been deleted from iTunes Connect (even though it was letting me log in). I created a new test account and it started to work. I believe the "Tap OK to download it now" message was actually an attempt to re-initiate the transaction, which would then fail again.

Comment: StoreKit error reporting is a complete cluster. please submit a bug report to: http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/bugrptform.html and maybe it will get better.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, turns out I was using an invalid test account (The test account was bound to a different apple developer account from the one the application was linked to). Checked test account credentials and everything was hunky dory.

@wdlindmeier: I see you also had the same solution: I'd suggest that you accept this answer or your own in case that helps anybody. :)

Answer (score 0):

I’ve met the same issue in sandbox environment and found it may related to SKPaymentTransactionObserver.

When I firstly implement this, I did alloc SKPaymentTransactionObserver and added it only when I started doing purchase. Also I removed SKPaymentTransactionObserver as soon as the transaction is succeed or failed. I found the transaction is always unfinished in this case, 
even I finished the transaction before removing SKPaymentTransactionObserver.

So my solution is, alloc a SKPaymentTransactionObserver when app started, then do NOT remove it until the app terminated. The “unfinished” transaction still to be finished correctly then.

Hope this is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this too.
It turns out you can't test in app purchases in the simulator!